# Cakephp3: How can I return json data?

Tags: json, cakephp

I am having a ajax post call to a cakePhp Controller:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'locations/add',
                data: {
                  abbreviation: $(jqInputs[0]).val(),
                  description: $(jqInputs[1]).val()
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if(response.status === "success") {
                        // do something with response.message or whatever other data on success
                        console.log('success');
                    } else if(response.status === "error") {
                        // do something with response.message or whatever other data on error
                        console.log('error');
                    }
                }
            });
```

When I try this I get the following error message:

> Controller actions can only return Cake\Network\Response or null.

Within the AppController I have this

```
$this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
```

enabled.

the Controller function looks  like this:

```
public function add()
{
    $this->autoRender = false; // avoid to render view

    $location = $this->Locations->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $location = $this->Locations->patchEntity($location, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Locations->save($location)) {
            //$this->Flash->success(__('The location has been saved.'));
            //return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            return json_encode(array('result' => 'success'));
        } else {
            //$this->Flash->error(__('The location could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            return json_encode(array('result' => 'error'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('location'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['location']);
}
```

What do I miss here? Is there any additional settings needed?

Comment: `Controller actions can only return Cake\Network\Response or null.` what is so unclear about this error message? You obviously return a string `return json_encode()`.

Comment: sorry, I still don't get the point?
I return an array, like in the example above?

Comment: You don't. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php And have you ever read this? http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

Comment: 1st don't return json just echo it so it will be printed in result. 2nd if you are not setting the header content type to json you have to mention it in the ajax like this dataType:'JSON'

Comment: @AmanRawat No, you do not echo data from a controller action! You either return a response object, echo data _in a template_, or use a serialized view.

Comment: @ndm, As the question says `$this->autoRender = false;` there is no view to render then?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Most answers I've seen here are either outdated, overloaded with unnecessary information, or rely on `withBody()`, which feels workaround-ish and not a CakePHP way.

Here's what worked for me instead:

```
$my_results = ['foo'=>'bar'];

$this->set([
    'my_response' => $my_results,
    '_serialize' => 'my_response',
]);
$this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
```

[More info on `RequestHandler`](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/request-handling.html#responding-to-requests). Seemingly it's not getting deprecated anytime soon.

**UPDATE**: CakePHP 4

```
$this->set(['my_response' => $my_results]);
$this->viewBuilder()->setOption('serialize', true);
$this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
```

[More info](https://api.cakephp.org/4.0/class-Cake.View.JsonView.html)

Comment: Also, `my_response` can be any valid key name, just needs to match in both places.

Comment: Also, this worked on CakePHP 3.6.10 (thought I should clarify)

Comment: It's not works without the component ! so It's not a general solution.

Comment: @MSS what component?

Comment: RequestHandler component is neaded

Comment: @MSS is there a problem with it?

Comment: yes 1th you dont mention it 2th it has use less overhead.

Comment: @MSS it's a built-in, default component. I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: Unfortunately I see that problem.

Comment: [testing.html#testing-a-json-responding-controller](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-a-json-responding-controller)

Answer (score 22):

Instead of returning the json_encode result, set the response body with that result and return it back.

```
public function add()
{
    $this->autoRender = false; // avoid to render view

    $location = $this->Locations->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $location = $this->Locations->patchEntity($location, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Locations->save($location)) {
            //$this->Flash->success(__('The location has been saved.'));
            //return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            $resultJ = json_encode(array('result' => 'success'));
            $this->response->type('json');
            $this->response->body($resultJ);
            return $this->response;
        } else {
            //$this->Flash->error(__('The location could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            $resultJ = json_encode(array('result' => 'error', 'errors' => $location->errors()));

            $this->response->type('json');
            $this->response->body($resultJ);
            return $this->response;
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('location'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['location']);
}
```

## Edit (credit to @Warren Sergent)

Since CakePHP 3.4, we should use

```
return $this->response->withType("application/json")->withStringBody(json_encode($result));
```

Instead of :

```
$this->response->type('json');
$this->response->body($resultJ);
return $this->response;
```

[CakePHP Documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#setting-the-body)

Comment: This: $this->response->type('json'); and $this->response->body($resultJ); helped me lot, thanks!

Comment: I updated the anwser to include the validation errors.

Comment: Worth noting that since CakePHP 3.4, this is no longer valid. You should instead use `return $this->response->withType("application/json")->withStringBody(json_encode($result));` which allows for passing a string to the immutable response.

Answer (score 8):

there are few things to return `JSON` response:

1. load `RequestHandler` component
2. set rendering mode as `json`
3. set content type
4. set required data
5. define `_serialize` value

for example you can move first 3 steps to some method in parent controller class:

```
protected function setJsonResponse(){
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
    $this->response->type('application/json');
}
```

later in your controller you should call that method, and set required data;

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $location = $this->Locations->patchEntity($location, $this->request->data);

    $success = $this->Locations->save($location);

    $result = [ 'result' => $success ? 'success' : 'error' ];

    $this->setJsonResponse();
    $this->set(['result' => $result, '_serialize' => 'result']);
}
```

also it looks like you should also check for `request->is('ajax)`; I'm not sure about returning `json` in case of `GET` request, so `setJsonResponse` method is called within `if-post` block;

in your ajax-call success handler you should check `result` field value:

```
success: function (response) {
             if(response.result == "success") {
                 console.log('success');
             } 
             else if(response.result === "error") {
                    console.log('error');
             }
         }
```

Comment: that one is a handy answer ! BRAVO

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of CakePHP `$this->response->type()` and `$this->response->body()` are deprecated.

Instead you should use `$this->response->withType()` and `$this->response->withStringBody()`

**E.g:**

(*this was pinched from the accepted answer*)

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $location = $this->Locations->patchEntity($location, $this->request->data);
    if ($this->Locations->save($location)) {
        //$this->Flash->success(__('The location has been saved.'));
        //return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        $resultJ = json_encode(array('result' => 'success'));

        $this->response = $this->response
            ->withType('application/json') // Here
            ->withStringBody($resultJ)     // and here

        return $this->response;
    }
}
```

[Relevant Documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#response)

Answer (score 0):

When you return JSON data you need to define the data type and response body information like below:

```
$cardInformation = json_encode($cardData);
$this->response->type('json');
$this->response->body($cardInformation);
return $this->response;
```

In you case just change this `return json_encode(array('result' => 'success'));` line with below code:

```
$responseResult = json_encode(array('result' => 'success'));
$this->response->type('json');
$this->response->body($responseResult);
return $this->response;
```

Answer (score 0):

RequestHandler is not required to send json.
In controller's action:

```
$this->viewBuilder()->setClassName('Json');
$result = ['result' => $success ? 'success' : 'error'];
$this->set($result);
$this->set('_serialize', array_keys($result));
```

Answer (score 0):

As of cakePHP 4.x.x the following should work assuming that your controller and routes are set as shown below:
**controller: *<your_project_name>/src/Controller/StudentsController.php***

```
public function index()
    {
        $students = $this->Students->find('all');
        $this->set(compact('students'));
        $this->viewBuilder()->setOption('serialize',['students']);
    }
```

**Routes: *<your_project_name>/config/routes.php***

```
<?php

use Cake\Routing\Route\DashedRoute;
use Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder;

/** @var \Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder $routes */
$routes->setRouteClass(DashedRoute::class);

$routes->scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $builder) {
 
    $builder->setExtensions(['json']);
    $builder->resources('Students');
    $builder->fallbacks();
});
```

Run **bin/cake server** and visit **http://localhost:8765/students.json** using postman/insomnia or just the normal browser.
See further documentation for setting up [Restful controllers](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/rest.html#the-simple-setup) and [Restful Routing](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/routing.html#resource-routes)

Don't forget to set the method to **GET** on postman and insomnia.

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not a CakePHP Guru, in my case i'm using cake > 4 and I need some results by ajax call. For this, from my controller i wrote,

> echo json_encode(Dashboard::recentDealers()); die;

and in my JS file i just need to parse the data using

> JSON.parse(data)

The ajax call like

```
 $.get('/recent-dealers', function (data, status) {
   console.log (JSON.parse(data)); });
});
```