# Ajax call not working properly in browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp-3.x

This is a code to display all the list of the customers in the tables. currently i just want to load it into the view page.

```
//controller code

public function disp(){
    if( $this->request->is('ajax') ) {
        $this->autoRender = false;
    }
    if ($this->request->isPost()) {
        // get values here 
        $customers = $this->Customers->find('all');
        echo json_encode($customers);
    }
}


//index code in the view

$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#example').DataTable( {
         ajax: {
             'type' : 'post',
             'url': '/disp',
             'dataType': 'json',
         },
     });
});

//routes

$routes->connect('/disp', ['controller' => 'Customers', 'action' => 'disp']);
```

Ajax call is giving a failure in the browser. Please tell me how to connect it to the function in the controller and return the results in json format in the view page?

Comment: ajax code is just to connect to the controller. I have not written code to display the json data

Comment: " giving a failure"...what's the status code and error message? Give us a clue

Comment: ajax call xhr error is displayed in the inspect element. No data is displayed in the view

Comment: you can check properly in the browser's console and/or network tools. You should be able to retrieve the actual HTTP status code and the response given by the server (if any). "XHR error" is just generic and explains nothing useful.

Comment: Your function should not be echoing output, but returning it in the response object. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41042107/cakephp3-how-can-i-return-json-data) is similar. Posting this as a comment instead of answer, because I'm not sure if this is your current problem, or something that will only start to bite you once your current problem is resolved.