# CakePHP4 Ajax: Send from Controller to View

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

I want to fetch data from the database and send it with Ajax in CakePhp4 from the controller to the view.

I've implemented it (rarely found documentations) but it doesnt return me the array. It wants a whole view, but I dont want to create a whole page, just return the array.

Error:
`The view for CountriesController::getAll() was not found.`

In my `src/controller/CountriesController.php`

```
        public function getAll() {


        $results = $this->Countries->find('all', [
                    'contain' => ['PLZ']
                ]);

                $this->set(compact('results')); 
                $this->set('_serialize', 'results'); 
    }
```

In my `template/countries/index.php`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'countries/getAll',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    },
    success: function(response) {
        if (response.error) {
            alert(response.error);
            console.log(response.error);
        }
        if (response.content) {
            $('#target').html(response.content);
        }
    },
    error: function(e) {
        alert("An error occurred: " + e.responseText.message);
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: Does [this part of the manual](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) help? Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378793/how-to-output-custom-http-body-contents-with-cakephp-3-4-echoing-causes-unable/42379581#42379581)? Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41042107/cakephp3-how-can-i-return-json-data/51859677)?

Comment: Yes thanks you and sorry. I will post my solution later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

config/routes.php

```
$routes->prefix('Api', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->setExtensions(['json']);
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

Controller/Api/CountriesController.php

```
public function getall()
{
    $countries = $this->Countries->find('all', [
        'contain' => ['PLZ']
    ]);

    $data = [
        'countries' => $countries,
    ];

    $this->set(compact('data'));
    $this->viewBuilder()->setOption('serialize', ['data']);
}
```

see if this works first:
/api/countries/getall.json